# Create new variable based on comparison between three other variables

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in my dataframe based on a row-wise comparison between three columns. An example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1986L, 1987L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L), knmilocatie = structure(c(4L, 16L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 20L, 12L, 12L, 25L, 9L, 30L, 26L, 22L, 18L, 15L, 24L, 13L, 31L, 27L, 5L, 3L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 26L, 26L, 31L, 35L, 25L, 11L, 28L, 8L, 29L, 36L, 34L, 7L, 28L, 17L, 14L, 33L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 32L, 27L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 2L), .Label = c("Achterdiep", "Annen", "Appingedam", "Assen", "Bedum", "De Klip", "Delfzijl", "Eenrum", "Eleveld", "Emmen", "Garsthuizen", "Geelbroek", "Haren", "Hellum", "Hoogezand", "Hooghalen", "Kolham", "Langelo", "Loppersum", "Middelstum", "Nijenklooster", "Noordbroek", "Oldenzijl", "Overschild", "Roswinkel", "Slochteren", "Stedum", "Steendam", "t-Zandt", "Ten Boer", "Ten Post", "Uithuizermeeden", "Weiwerd", "Westerbroek", "Winneweer", "Zandeweer"), class = "factor"), baglocatie = structure(c(2L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 17L, 11L, 2L, 21L, 2L, 16L, 35L, 27L, 14L, 22L, 19L, 33L, 34L, 26L, 17L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 28L, 6L, 25L, 25L, 29L, 9L, 21L, 10L, 19L, 34L, 15L, 36L, 13L, 7L, 19L, 8L, 23L, 7L, 31L, 17L, 1L, 20L, 3L, 10L, 32L, 30L, 24L), .Label = c("Appingedam", "Assen", "Bedum", "Ekehaar", "Emmen", "Eppenhuizen", "Farmsum", "Froombosch", "Garrelsweer", "Garsthuizen", "Geelbroek", "Hooghalen", "Kolham", "Langelo", "Leermens", "Loppersum", "Middelstum", "Oosterwijtwerd", "Overschild", "Roodeschool", "Roswinkel", "Sappemeer", "Schildwolde", "Schipborg", "Slochteren", "Stedum", "Steendam", "t-Zandt", "Ten Post", "Toornwerd", "Tripscompagnie", "Warffum", "Westerbroek", "Wirdum", "Woudbloem", "Zandeweer"), class = "factor"), lllocatie = structure(c(3L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 22L, 4L, 36L, 37L, 31L, 15L, 23L, 20L, 34L, 8L, 24L, 35L, 19L, 19L, 2L, 29L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 30L, 8L, 22L, 9L, 20L, 19L, 16L, 38L, 12L, 6L, 27L, 7L, 11L, 17L, 33L, 14L, 2L, 21L, 18L, 9L, 28L, 32L, 1L), .Label = c("Annen", "Appingedam", "Assen", "Eleveld", "Emmen", "Farmsum", "Froombosch", "Garrelsweer", "Garsthuizen", "Geelbroek", "Hellum", "Hoogezand", "Hooghalen", "Huizinge", "Langelo", "Leermens", "Meedhuizen", "Onderdendam", "Oosterwijtwerd", "Overschild", "Roodeschool", "Roswinkel", "Sappemeer", "Sint Annen", "Slochteren", "Startenhuizen", "Steendam", "Stitswerd", "t-Zandt", "Ten Post", "Tjuchem", "Toornwerd", "Tripscompagnie", "Westerbroek", "Westerwijtwerd", "Winneweer", "Woudbloem", "Zandeweer"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("year", "knmilocatie", "baglocatie", "lllocatie"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

When the values for the three columns (`"knmilocatie", "baglocatie", "lllocatie"`) are the same in a row (as is the case in the first three rows of the example dataframe), the new column should get the value `1` for that row representing the fact that there is only one unique value. When all three columns have different values (see row 11), the new column should get the value `3` for that row. When there are two unique values in the comparison, it should get the value `2`.

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: apply(df, 1, function(u) length(unique(u))) ?

Comment: @droopy.  Perhaps you meant `apply(df[-1], 1, function(u) length(table(u)))` .

Comment: @droopy thanx, `apply(df[,-1], 1, function(u) length(unique(u)))` gave me the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two possibilities :

```
apply(df[,-1], 1, function(u) length(unique(u))) # as you corrected it
colSums(!apply(df[,-1], 1, duplicated))
```

The second possibility could be faster if you have a large data set.
HTH